# Solution verification: Proving that $\mathbb Q$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $(\mathbb Q, \tau_1)$ be a subtopology of the euclidean topology $\mathbb R$. Is the topological space $(\mathbb Q, \tau_1)$ connected?

I answered affirmative and made a proof for this, however, I searched this online and I read that the topological space $(\mathbb Q, \tau_1)$ is not connected, meaning that my proof is incorrect.

---

#### My proof

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is connected if the only clopened subsets are $X$ and $\emptyset$.

So, let $A \in \tau_1$ such that $A \neq \mathbb Q$ and $A \neq \emptyset$.

Let $\mathcal{B}_1 = \{(a,b) \cap \mathbb Q: (a,b) \subset \mathbb R\}$, with $a < b$, be a basis for $\tau_1$.

Then we have that
$$\begin{align}
&A = \bigcup \limits _i (a_i ,b_i)\cap \mathbb{Q}=
\\
\\
&= \mathbb Q \cap \bigcup_i (a_i,b_i)
\end{align}
$$

Let's now consider the set $\mathbb Q \setminus A$:

$$\begin{align}
&\mathbb Q \setminus A =\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb Q \cup \mathbb Q \setminus \bigcup_i (a_i,b_i)
\\
\\
&= \bigcap _i \mathbb Q \setminus (a_i,b_i)
\end{align}
$$

We have that $\mathbb Q \setminus (a_i,b_i)= ((-\infty, a_i] \cup [b_i, \infty)) \cap \mathbb Q$. So we conclude that:

$$\mathbb Q \setminus A = \mathbb Q \cap \bigcap _i ((-\infty, a_i] \cup [b_i, \infty))$$.

We have that $\bigcap _i ((-\infty, a_i] \cup [b_i, \infty))$ is never an open set of $\mathbb R$, so we conclude that $\mathbb Q \cap \bigcap _i ((-\infty, a_i] \cup [b_i, \infty)) \notin \tau_1 \to \mathbb Q \setminus A \notin \tau_1$, so $A$ is not clopen, proving that $(\mathbb Q, \tau_1)$ is a connected set.

---

What did I do wrong in my proof?

Comment: What are the $a_i$ and the $b_i$?

Comment: $(a_i, b_i)$ for some index set $i \in I$, is a family of open intervals in $\mathbb R$, such that $A = \bigcup _i ((a_i,b_i) \cap \mathbb Q)$ @CharlesHudgins

Comment: Here's a counterexample: $(-\infty,\sqrt2)\cap\Bbb Q$ is clopen in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if $\Omega\subseteq \Bbb R$ is open, then $\Omega\cap \Bbb Q$ is open in the subspace topology of $\Bbb Q$. It is not true that, if $\Omega\subseteq \Bbb R$ is not open, then $\Omega\cap\Bbb Q$ is not open in the subspace topology of $\Bbb Q$. For instance, $\Bbb Q$ is not open in $\Bbb R$, yet $\Bbb Q\cap \Bbb Q$ is open in the subspace topology of $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 4):

You assume that from the fact that $(-\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$ is not open in $\Bbb R$, that it follows that its intersection with $\Bbb Q$ cannot be open. Well, if you take $a=\sqrt{2}, b= \sqrt{5}$, say, then in fact

$$\left((-\infty, \sqrt{2}] \cup [\sqrt{5}, \infty)\right) \cap \Bbb Q = \left((-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cup (\sqrt{5}, \infty)\right) \cap \Bbb Q$$

as the "boundary points" are not rational, and so the set *does* have an open intersection with $\Bbb Q$ after all.